# How can I lock a SQL Server Login programatically. Emulate a users invalid attempts

Tags: sql

I need to programatically lock a SQL Server Login.  The goal is to emulate the automatic function in SQL That will lock out a user that makes several connection attempts with a bad password.

I can easily unlock a login, but I need to lock it as well.

I have tried looping through 20 times with a vb.net sqlConnection that contained an invalid password and I get very inconsistent results.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605814/locking-user-account-created-under-windows-authentication-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

How about just scripting our a [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) request?

Seems like you could easily create a script that calls some resource on the server very quickly and very often to do this.